# How does wordpress know about its functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

Specifically in theme php files, such as say index.php.  The very first thing in most theme's index.php file is a call to get_header() which is most certainly not not defined in index.php, so how does it know about that function?

I'm not very familiar with php, but from what I've read just now there is an include and require keyword which work more or less the same way as an [<strike>import in Java or</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java)  include in C, which I understand and makes sense.  However, the only usage of these keywords in this particular index.php file includes a file that doesn't contain a definition of get_header(), nor does it have any includes or requires of its own (though it does call some more functions it has no right to know about, much like index) so clearly that's now how it knows about this function.

Anyway, I was just hoping to remove some of the 'magic' from wordpress for myself.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themes' index.php file is not the main file that's processed, that one resides in the root directory of your wordpress installation. It calls several files setting up the environment and then loads the template. You might want to look in the `wp-content/plugins` directory, maybe starting with the `globals.php` file to tweak some of the magic.

Also the `wp-includes` directory contains interesting files, the `get_header()` function is defined in `general-template.php` in that directory.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly the sort of answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

The index.php in each theme isn't ever called directly, rather those are included by other files in Wordpress.

`get_header` is actually defined in `wp-includes/general-template.php`.

The templates files are loaded by `require_once` function calls in the `load_template` function of `wp-includes/theme.php`

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically in theme php files, such as say index.php. The very first thing in most theme's index.php file is a call to get_header() which is most certainly not not defined in index.php, so how does it know about that function?

A theme's `index.php` file is never executed on its own. **All** requests to a WordPress install go through the main WordPress `index.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, index.php is being included in another file and that file either defines the get_header() function or - more likely - contains yet another included php file which in turns defines the get_header() function.

You have to understand that the php *include* and *require* functions behave like an in-line include. It simply treats the include file as being part of the original script.. a big concatenated script (so not really like an *import* in Java)

You may want to start at the .htaccess file which will tell you which .php file is assigned to handle the request. Based on what you said in your question, it will probably not be index.php. When you find the top-most php script, you can work your way from there with the *include*s and *requires*..

Comment: Whoops, you are correct about it not being similar to java import, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

in c and in java you declare the import at the top of you files. In php you can set the includes almost anyware you want.

so this is valid:

```
<?php 
// define some functions
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
include('head.php');
?>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

it is possible that these `get_header()` methods are declared somewhere before the index.php page is included.

If you want to leave out the `<?php get_header(); ?>` then there will be no problem