# create slide show with button bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a main activity that changing back ground by swipping the image and and on left side i want to put a button bar that contain 4 buttons to move to 4 different activities so i write the folloning code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button[]  buttons = new Button[4]; 
SharedPreferences fsc;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;   
private Context mContext;

private final GestureDetector detector = new SwipeGestureDetector();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            addListenerOnButton();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this;
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
private void addListenerOnButton() {
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slide);

    buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    slideshow.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    );
class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_out));                  
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.right_out));
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it says that i have error  Type SwipeGestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type  line 29 Java Problem any one helps me

Comment: Is this your entire `.java` file?

Comment: yes this is but i put only one button for trying

Answer (score 0):

You aren't `import`ing the library classes you need. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java) may be helpful.

It looks like you're doing this by hand in a basic text editor. Using an IDE like Eclipse (which has good Android tools) will keep you from having to do all this by hand.

Comment: t android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;