# What will the following import declaration import?

Tags: java, import

```
java.io.Reader.*;
```

I know that `Reader` is a class, not a package.

So, what the above declaration will import?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java)

Comment: Just to be a bit technical: Java has [_import declarations_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), not import [_statements_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5). However, the code fragments you posted are neither. The first would be legal as part of an `import` declaration and the second as part of an `import static` declaration.

Comment: @TedHopp : `java.io.Reader.*` does not import static members of the class.

Comment: @kevingomes - `java.io.Reader.*;` is not a declaration at all and it is impossible to say what it might mean until you tell us whether it is part of a type import (`import java.io.Reader.*;`) or a static import (`import static java.io.Reader.*;`).

Comment: @TedHopp : I think I am confusing you. Please check my edited straight forward question

Comment: You keep changing your question. As it reads now, the answer is that it will import nothing, since `java.io.Reader` has no (visible) subclasses.

Comment: @TedHopp : That's all I wanted to know. Previously I don't know what you were saying. Make an answer of your last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration:

```
import java.io.Reader.*;
```

is an example of a *type-import-on-demand* declaration. From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2):

> A type-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible types of a named package or type to be imported as needed.

Since `java.io.Reader` contains no nested classes or other accessible types, the declaration would simply be ignored.

Note that Java also has an `import static` declaration. So

```
import static java.io.Reader.*;
```

would be an example of a *static-import-on-demand* declaration. Again, according to the Java Language Specification:

> A static-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible static members of a named type to be imported as needed.

And since `java.io.Reader` also has no accessible static members, the declaration would again be ignored.

Comment: will it import any `subclass` of the imported class (IF ANY)

Comment: @kevingomes - Yes, it will import (on demand) any subclasses of the imported class, provided they are accessible. Note that it will not import `java.io.Reader` itself, however. You'd need a separate `import` declaration for that.

Comment: `Provided they are accessible`, means?

Comment: @kevingomes - If a subclass is `private`, it is not accessible. if it has default access (no qualifier) then it is accessible only to members of the `java.io` package; if it is `protected`, it is accessible to members of the `java.io` package and to any subtypes of `java.io.Reader` regardless of package; if it is `public` then it is accessible to any code. See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: You said, `If a subclass is private, it is not accessible`.  As far as I know, `private` modifier is not allowed before a class name i.e. `private class-name {}`, is not allowed

Comment: @kevingomes - First, I misstated things. A `private` subclass is accessible to other members of the containing class. Second, you are correct that top-level classes can only have `public` or default access, but I was talking about _nested_ classes. All access modifiers are allowed for nested classes (whether they are static nested classes or inner classes). The link at the end of my previous comment discusses this distinction.

Answer (score 2):

In the same file you can have both

```
import java.io.Reader;          //Statement 1

import static java.io.Reader.*;        //Statement 2
```

the first one is importing only the class `Reader` from package `java.io`,
the second one is importing all the static members of class Reader, wich appears to be only

```
private static final int maxSkipBufferSize = 8192;
```

so, pretty useless, because being it private you cannot access it from your class, neither for reading nor for modifying

Comment: are `import static java.io.Reader.*` and `import java.io.Reader.*` same?

Comment: the scond one will result in a compiler error, but you can write `import java.io.*` to import all classes in the package `java.io`

Comment: @kevingomes - They are not at all the same. Read [Section 7.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) to learn all about it.

Comment: @LuigiCortese - The second one doesn't result in a compiler error. Rather, since `Reader` has no static members, the statement will simply be ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1 will include the Reader Class that you can use in your code, as this class is used to read the character stream

Statement 2 will include all the Classes from Reader.* Package ( if it is a package), i am assuming it generic

Comment: The meaning of declaration 2 would depend on whether this is an `import` or `import static` declaration. (However, since `java.io.Reader` has no accessible nested classes or static members, it's pretty much a useless declaration in either case.)