# "import java.util.*; or import java.util.random;"

Tags: java, import

How do the statements "import java.util.*;" and "import java.util.Random;" differ from each other? Why would you use one over another?

This is a question from my book, and I can't find a good answer, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is import done in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053658/how-is-import-done-in-java)

Comment: The first version imports all packages from the 'utils', needed or not. The second imports a single specific package only. chose the second one if you like typing or expect name conflicts. IDE tools usually create imports for you in the second form.

Comment: @Serge Neither imports any packages. They both import classes.

Comment: @user207421 sure, it imports all classes, interfaces and annotations from a package.

Comment: @Serge And not packages, contrary to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

"import java.util.*;" adds all the utils under the utils package including Scanner, Random etc...  and "import java.util.Random; just only import the Random util to your code.

Comment: `Random` is not a 'util', and neither is anything else imported by the `import` statement. The word is 'class'.

Comment: Ok. Thanks sir. I'm a fresher to java and not very rich with the technical terms